# Find the closed form for the following power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, formal-power-series

I wish to find the closed form for this power series:
$1+\dfrac{1}{6}x+\dfrac{3}{40}x^2+\dfrac{5}{112}x^3+\dfrac{35}{1152}x^4...$

I have been able to spot the that the second term is the first term multiply with $\dfrac{1 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 3}$, the third term is the second term multiply with $\dfrac{3 \cdot 3}{4 \cdot 5}$, the fourth term is the third term multiply with
$\dfrac{5 \cdot 5}{6 \cdot 7}$, the fifth term is the fourth term multiply with
$\dfrac{7 \cdot 7}{8 \cdot 9}$ and so on.

How do I start to find the closed form for this series? It is taken from James Stirling's Methodus Differentialis. The author doesn't present a closed form

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (in terms of a systematic approach), but your ability to spot patterns is pretty remarkable.  You are probably in the right field of work.

Comment: @ad2004: The pattern is provided in Stirling's book, I can only guess the first term, all other terms are provided by Stirling. So the credit goes to him, not to me. Thank you for your compliment, though.

Comment: It can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n+1)!} x^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
But I am not sure how to get a closed form for this.

Comment: If it helps, $$\arcsin x = x+\frac16x^3+\frac3{40}x^5+\frac5{112}x^7+\frac{35}{1152}x^9+\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you, I have expanded arcsine function but did not remember its series representation. I don't know how to modify this to obtain Stirling's series. If divide both sides by x, I only get $1+\dfrac{1}{6}x^2+\dfrac{3}{40}x^4+\dfrac{5}{112}x^6...$, close enough, but not quite there yet.

Comment: See equation $(18)$ here ... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html

Comment: It is series expansion for $\arcsin(x)$, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments we have for $|x|\lt1$
$$\arcsin{(x)}=x+\frac16x^3+\frac3{40}x^5+\frac5{112}x^7+\dots$$
Hence the provided power series is just
$$1+\frac16x+\frac3{40}x^2+\frac5{112}x^3+\dots=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\\frac{\arcsin{(\sqrt{x})}}{\sqrt{x}}&x\ne0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you are right with the expression $\dfrac{\arcsin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$. Thank you! But there is complex analysis in this case?

Comment: $arcsin(z)$ is an entire function? You might want to reconsider your domain.

Comment: @SeanNemetz I am unsure how one deals with the $\sqrt{x}$ in this case because it appears that $\arcsin{(\sqrt{x})}/\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous real function for $-1\lt x\lt1$ using the principal branch of the square root.